# "Sense of Smell" vs. "Smell"

Tags: etymology, grammaticality, phrases, word-usage, nouns

Why do we refer to most senses by just their names: "poor hearing" or "poor sight", but, rather oddly, say "poor *sense of* smell"?

Comment: We **don't** say "poor taste", or "poor touch" either, to describe people with a sensory deficit. To say that we refer to senses "just by their names" doesn't really mean anything: "sense of smell" is a name.  Do you mean "Why isn't there a single word to describe the ability to smell things?"

Comment: Apparently there is: https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/smell

Comment: @MaxWilliams yes, I suppose I do.

Comment: @Helmar, I too first checked a dictionary and saw something similar; is it just a convention then?

Comment: you effectively say "that person has a poor sight/hearing" because these words are not ambiguous, They apply only about the sense of the person subject to the sentence. Whereas for smell, you don't know if you're talking about the smell, the odor coming from the subject or his sense. He has a bad smell can be interpreted both ways: the smell coming from the person or his sense , same with taste, you could be a cannibal and the sentence be about the taste of the flesh of the subject. With sight the auxilliary used is disambiguous enough He is a poor sight vs He has a poor sight leaves no doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Because in the case of smell (and taste and touch), the name of the sense is same as the name of the thing being sensed.  Basically, the speaker is avoiding the following second-grader's joke:

> Q: If you cut off a goat's nose, how would it smell?
>    A: Terrible!